# Getting an error in FBSDKApplicationDelegate class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, facebook

I'm getting an error when I build my xCode 7.3.1 project.

> /Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKApplicationDelegate.h:77:35: No type or protocol named 'UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey'

Problem func like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options;
```

Need your help! Thx..

Answer (score 17):

The Latest FBSDKCoreKit does'nt work with Xcode 7.3. You should use XCode 8 or older versions of Facebook framework.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options
```

has been replaced in XCode 8 as

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
        options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options;
```

Try this facebook SDK instead

https://origincache.facebook.com/developers/resources/?id=FacebookSDKs-iOS-4.14.0.zip

For more information on changes from iOS 9 to 10 , go to this link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/iOS10APIDiffs/Objective-C/UIKit.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url 
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
    annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
  ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}
```

Use this code :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                        openURL:url
                                              sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                     annotation:annotation
          ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url options:options];

}
```